# Design decision for custom view

Tags: java, android

I want to design a custom card view which displays information about a duel in an android app. Here is a screenshot of what the view looks like right now.

[image: Custom Card View]

The image and the green button should be clickable, however, this design is currently done in one custom view extending CardView. The green button is a Rectangle and the polygon is a filled Path which overlays the button.

Because I have done everything in one `onDraw()` method, there is no `onClick()` method for solely the button or solely the image. Is there any clever way to do this? Maybe I'm conceptually wrong somewhere?

---

My thoughts so far:

- Have a transparent button on top of the green button in the xml
- Maybe there is a way to include a button in the `onDraw()` method
- Make the whole view clickable and include the image in the xml

Comment: What is the reason you are doing it all in `onDraw` method? Why have you decided to not go with viewgroup for this (which would let you to actually have the separate clickable parts)?

Comment: To add to the matter, a `CardView` does extend `ViewGroup` in SDK, so there's literally no reason to not have the button as a separate component.

Comment: Why can't you simply use standard Views? It would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I understand there is an addView() function which is extended from ViewGroup. However, I don't know how to show the button in the view. Is it also possible to overlap the button with the polygon? Sidenote: I'm really new to android development so I just tried how this might work.

Comment: You can define these layouts in many ways, for example via XML which your view will inflate when created. As for overlapping, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792496/is-there-any-way-to-have-ui-elements-slightly-overlap-one-on-top-of-one-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it now. I changed the custom view to only display the skewed rectangle. The other resources were created in a seperate xml file. With an `<include />`, I was able to place the rectangle over the button.